# Scrollbar outside viewstack

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, scroll, scrollbar

Consider this example. I have two views in viewstack. One has a VRule extending from top of screen to bottom. Another view has a big accordion.

If I give viewstack percent height=100%, first view works fine and second view gets clipped or has a vertical scroll bar inside view stack.

If I dont mention viewstack height and set resizeToContent to true, second view works fine and  first view takes up only small part of screen.

If I mention viewstack height and set resizeToContent to true, first view works fine and second view gets clipped or has a vertical scroll bar inside view stack.

I want vertical scrollbar but for entire window, not just for viewstack. How to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have given some specific height to accordion.

Comment: No. I havent mentioned height.